# How to distribute and resize elements using fxFlex?

Tags: html, css, angular, flexbox, angular-flex-layout

**The goal**

I'm trying to write my own search bar for mat-table. The search bar consists only of inputs - one for each column. I placed it right above the table and now I'm trying to distribute them equally with the help of flex-layout, like the table does with its columns.

**The problem**

But the problem is that those inputs don't listen to me and don't shrink but they overflow outside the wrapping element. I need them to shrink equally to fit in the wrapping `section` but I don't know how to do this.

**The code**

Here is the sample of the code I wrote so far:

```html
    <section fxLayout="row" class="search-table" style="overflow-x: auto;">
        <mat-form-field *ngFor="let item of items" fxFlex>
            <input matInput type="text" placeholder="sample text" fxFlex>
        </mat-form-field>
    </section>
```

```css
    .search-table {
        border: 1px solid black;
    }
```

#### EDIT

[Here's](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-cmfuc4) stackblitz example of my problem. Flex-layout don't work there for some reason so I added flex to css.

Comment: Any stackblitz working example could help to debug the issue.

Comment: Just give me a minute

Comment: What do you mean by dont listen to you and dont shrink? whats the requirement what you need?

Comment: For example if I have 5 inputs, I'd like them to fill all of their `section` wrapper's width and remain inline as I resize the browser.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem comes from the `.mat-form-field-infix` class which sets a width of `180px` on the input.

**Solution:** Add the class below to the `styles.css` file

```
.mat-form-field-infix {
  width: auto!important;
}
```

**StackBlitz:** [here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/stackoverflow-how-to-distribute-and-resize-elements-using-flex?file=src/styles.css)